# How to include pip packages in an rpm build

Tags: python, pip, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I want to include a Python package dependency (installed using `pip3 install`) in an `rpm` package. I cannot install using `dnf` because its version is out of date. `rpm` returns the following error if I install the dependency using `pip3 install`:

```
error: Failed dependencies python3.6dist(dependency-package)
```

Any suggestions on how to include a Python package inside of an `rpm`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK. Some of your package require `python3-somepackage` or `python3dist(somepackage)`. For rpm, it is just a string. Rpm does not care that the python module has been installed using pip. There must be some package which provides that string.

You have two options.

Prefered is use of `pyp2rpm --srpm somepackage`. That will download the latest version of the module from PyPI and produce the src.rpm. You can then build it using `mock -r epel-8-x86_64 somepackage.src.rpm`

The other option is to fake the provides. You can install the module using pip and then run: `create-fake-rpm --build python3-somepackage 'python3dist(somepackage)'`. This will generate the file `fake-python3-somepackage-0-0.noarch.rpm` which you can install using rpm. Then you can proceed with the install of your application. Be warned, that this is cheating. Future `dnf upgrade` will not update this module, you will have to take care of that yourself.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm getting the error: Failed dependencies: python3.6dist(packagename)  during rpm build but works fine when using `python3-package`. Is there any other option than using pyp2rpm or other third party. I specified the package in requirement.txt also.